# flask+uwsgi+supervisor set environment variable

Tags: flask, uwsgi, supervisord

I'm using `flask` with `uwsgi` to connect with `nginx`.

Also used `supervisor` to daemonize uwsgi.

In flask source, to get environment variable, use this code.

`os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIGURATION') or 'development'`

And in my .bashrc, I set environment variable like this.

```
export FLASK_CONFIGURATION=production
export NEWRELIC_KEY=12345
```

But it still works with `development`.

Refer the google, uwsgi launch isolated with bash, so it can't read environment varible.

So I set variable to uwsgi.

```
FLASK_CONFIGURATION = $(FLASK_CONFIGURATION)
NEWRELIC_KEY = $(NEWRELIC_KEY)
```

But it still doesn't work.

Is there any solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you supervisord config file for running uwsgi, you can add `environment` as below:

```
environment=FLASK_CONFIGURATION="production",NEWRELIC_KEY="12345"
```

ref: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html
sample: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/skel/sample.conf#L98

Comment: It is uwsgi version issue. Have to install via pip. Not apt-get. Anyway, thanks!